# Creating Cards with a Modal for each Card from an array using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, v-for

I am creating 6 Cards from an array using v-for successfully.
The issue is that I am also trying to create a Modal for each Card which contains each card's the unique card details. For exmaple: The card's title, link, author, img, category inside the Modal

I am able to generate the Modals but it is displaying the first card's details for all the cards.

You can see this if you look at the fiddle.

How do I generate a modal for each card with its own card details?

I am using bootstrap 4

```js
class Project {
    constructor(title, link, author, img, category) {
        this.title = title,
        this.link = link,
        this.author = author, 
        this.img = img,
        this.category = category
    }
}

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
        currentFilter: 'ALL',
        projectList: [
            new Project (
                'Ecommerce', 
                '#', 
                'Dessert Tools za', 
                'https://placeimg.com/460/180/any',
                'DESIGN'
          ),
            new Project (
                'BITC Management', 
                'https://digitalassetmanagement.com/', 
                'Widen',
                'https://placeimg.com/420/180/any',
                'DESIGN'
            ),
            new Project (
                'Landing Page', 
                'https://meet-a-geek.today/', 
                'Contenforces', 
                'https://placeimg.com/430/180/any',
                'DEVELOPMENT'
            ),
            new Project (
                'Online Training', 
                'https://www.smarttraining.com/', 
                'Smart Training LCC',
                'https://placeimg.com/440/180/any',
                'DEVELOPMENT'
            ),
            new Project (
                'Univesity & Jobsite Portal', 
                'https://micencostagebank.nl/index_september.php', 
                'Contenforces', 
                'https://placeimg.com/470/180/any',
                'COLABORATION'
            ),
            
            new Project (
                'Product Funnel', 
                'http://prettyexcellent.com/applecider/', 
                'A. A. Ron',
                'https://placeimg.com/480/180/any',
                'DEVELOPMENT'
            )
        ], 
    },

 methods: {
  setFilter: function setFilter(filter) {
   this.currentFilter = filter;
        } 
    }
    
});
```

```css
.section-subnav {
/* margin: $margin-xl 0; */


} 

.title {
text-align: center;       
/* font-size: $font-lg; */
font-weight:normal;
/* padding: $margin-sm 0; */
}

.submenu {
text-align: center;
/* font-size: $font-sm; */
/* margin-bottom: $margin-md; */

}

.filter {    
padding: 6px 6px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 6px;
transition: all 0.35s;
}

.filter.active {
box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px #00000026;
}
.filter:hover {
background:lightgray;
}     

.projects {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;    
justify-content: center;
}

p {
text-align: center;
/* font-size: $font-sm; */      
}

a {
/* font-size: $font-sm; */
color: #fff;
}

.projects-leave-to{
transform: translatey(30px);
opacity:0;
}

.project {
transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
margin: 0 10px;
width: 250px;
height: auto;
transition: all .35s ease-in-out;    
}

.project-image {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.project-description {
margin: 20px 10px;
text-align: center;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">     


        <section class="section-subnav" id="submenu-sec">
            <h3 class="title">Projects</h3>

            <div class="filters submenu">
                <span class="filter" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'ALL' }" v-on:click="setFilter('ALL')">ALL</span>
    
                <span class="filter" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'DESIGN' }" v-on:click="setFilter('DESIGN')">DESIGN</span>
    
                <span class="filter" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'DEVELOPMENT' }" v-on:click="setFilter('DEVELOPMENT')">DEVELOPMENT</span>
    
                <span class="filter" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'COLABORATION' }" v-on:click="setFilter('COLABORATION')">COLABORATION</span>
            </div>
        
       
            <div class="container">          

                <transition-group class="projects" name="projects">               
                    
                    <div class="rounded project" v-if="currentFilter === project.category || currentFilter === 'ALL'" v-bind:key="project.title" 
                        v-for="project in projectList"> 
                        
                         <!-- Modal pop up -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true" v-for="project in projectList">
               
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content" >
                                        
                                    <div class="modal-header"> 
                                        <img class="project-image " v-bind:src="project.img">  
                                    </div>
                            
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p class="project-title">{{project.title}}</p>
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
                                         
                                        </h5>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                        
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                        
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                            
                        <div class="border shadow border-ligh project-image-wrapper mb-5">
                                               
                            <img class="project-image " v-bind:src="project.img">                    
                        
                            <div class="project-description">
                                <p class="project-title">{{project.title}}</p>

                                <a :href="project.link" class="btn btn-danger" target="_blank">View Website</a>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                    View Details
                                </button>
                            </div>                           
                        </div>                                           
                    </div>         
                                    
                </transition-group>                
            </div><!-- container end -->          
            
        </section> 
        
    </div>
```

Here is a fiddle link
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YariAndres/m6gk2wbv/9/)

Comment: I would suggest you to use a library, it would be much easier and much less code for you to maintain, for example https://bootstrap-vue.js.org

Comment: Yes, though about that and I put it to my employer but they are stubborn and don't wont a lib. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need unique id in data. You can assign that to modal id like

```
:id="'myModal'+ project.id"
```

otherwise follow the instructions of @Lassi mentioned in the answer.

I forked your fiddle and passing project.title in the Modal ID  && button data-target .

```
 <div class="modal fade" :id="'myModal-'+project.title.replace(/[\W_]+/g,'_')" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true" v-for="project in projectList">
......
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" :data-target="'#myModal-'+project.title.replace(/[\W_]+/g,'_')">
                                View Details
                            </button>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3zv7jope/

Below is passing index example

```
v-for="(project, index) in projectList" :id="'myModal-'+index"
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/g3u50fpz/

Comment: OK, I have followed both instructions @dagalti & Lassi and works great. Thanks so much to you both for your explanations, it really helped.

Comment: @Lassi - as above.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about this you can do this! Sure thing @dagalti.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have duplicate v-for so you should remove the v-for from the modal element.

Your modal is inside the loop, so for every project in the DOM there is a hidden modal element. They all have the same id which is myModal. When you click view details, the first modal which is for the first item is displayed.

One way to solve this would be to add a unique modal id for each element. For example if we want to use the item index in the array we can add use the following way of constructing the id. Now each element has a unique id from myModal0 to myModal5. When you click view details now and Bootstrap searches for the modal to open it know what the right modal is.

```
                    <div class="modal fade" :id="'myModal' + i">
                    <button type="button" :data-target="'#myModal' + i">
```